# JS Can not use click function after append

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I add my TRIGGER DIV A over `$(".DIVB").html(data); from a AJAx Response`but when i now want to trigger some code over the $(".TRIGGER DIV A").click(function() it isnt working. Can someone explain me why ? And is there a Way to fix this or is there a working arround ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're using jQuery's `.click()`. If HTML is added dynamically to the DOM, you need to bind the click event to the element after it has been added. Otherwise, when `$(".TRIGGER DIV A").click(handler)` runs and jQuery looks for the element to bind, it isn't able to find it.

You may consider using `.delegate()` instead. This ensures that the event is bound to all elements relevant to the given selector regardless of when it is added to the DOM. You can find the documentation for usage here: http://api.jquery.com/delegate/

Comment: Got it by my own :D Thanks much dude!